# Odd Input Submit Tag Styling Behavior

Tags: html, css

I noticed that input tags don't pick up css styling unless certain properties are included (i.e., background-color, border).  Can anyone explain this default behavior, and explain any workarounds?

Let's assume we have an `<input type="submit">`.  The font size won't be applied unless we uncomment out the `background-color: red;`

```
input {
  font-size: 100px;
/*   background-color: red; */
}
```

This is a codepen showing the functionality.. you can uncomment the second css line to see the font-size change..

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JRgvNy

Thanks!

Comment: Looks fine in Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Hey James - I'm using chrome as well.  When you open the codepen and change the font size to anything else you are seeing a change?